# Using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow to display slices of a 3d array

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, imshow

I have some data with the shape (128, 1500, 1500) representing 128 images of size [1500,1500]. This is an astronomical dataset; the first axis represents frequency, and the other 2 axes represent RA/DEC.  I want to be able to use a Matplotlib slider (or something similar) to iterate through the 0th (frequency) axis and in order to view the image in each channel without having to manually re-plot each time. However, I've never used the mpl Slider before, so I'm not sure how to get started here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using `mpl_interactions.hyperslicer` - which will automatically generate the slider for you and also works with higher dimensional arrays. https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/hyperslicer.html  it also integrates with xarray to use coords so that values of the sliders aren't just indices but values.

Comment: You can also use `mpl-interactions.ipyplot.imshow` https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/imshow.html

Comment: Alternatively you can make your own. In the sliders `on_changed` callback you should do: `im.set_data(arr[slider.val])` where `im`  is the return value of `imshow`